# Finding a harmonic function on half-disk that is equal to $1$ on the semi-circle and $0$ on the diameter

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I first showed that the mapping

$$z + \frac{1}{z}$$

sends the upper semi-disk, $\{|z|<1, \operatorname{Im} z >0\}$, along with the real line from $-1$ to $1$, to the whole of the real line in the w-plane.

Specifically, it sends the upper semi-circular arc to the real interval $[-2,2]$, and sends $[-1,1]$ to the rest of the real line in the $w$-plane.

Now I want to find a harmonic function taking values $T=1$ on the arc, and $T=0$ along $[-1,1]$.

The arc mapping to an interval $[-2,2]$ makes it problematic to use the harmonic $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ function.

I have tried scaling and translating the function but still not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The arc mapping to an interval $[-2,2]$ makes it problematic to use the harmonic $\arg(z)$ function

But only a little. You can use 
$$\frac{1}{\pi}(\arg(w-2) -\arg(w+2))$$
which evaluates to $1$ on $(-2,2)$ and to $0$ outside of $[-2,2]$. There is no limit at the points of discontinuity, but this is to be expected.

Comment: Got it, @NormalHuman - thanks so much for your answer.  I had already moved on and used one of the standard mappings -- going from the UHP to the unit disk, and inverting back, and then constructing the harmonic function from there.  But doing it your way was the point of the problem statement - continuing with the Joukowski transform.